# "Строго следовать"и "обязательно" - в чем разница

Tags: значение-слов

Добрый день!Пожалуйста,помогите разобраться,есть ли различия в смысловой нагрузке слов "Строго следовать"и "обязательно",например:между"строго следовать благословению" и "обязательно благословения".
Заранее благодарю,за ответ!

Comment: Вот так вот именно "благословени**я**"??? Тогда разница в том, что первое правильно, а второе - скорее всего грамматическая ошибка или косноязычие.

Answer (score 1):

Различие есть, и большое: первом случае связывать с последующим нужно глагол "следовать" (с его формальными и смысловыми особенностями), во втором - наречие "обязательно". По смыслу: в первом случае ссылаются на образец поведения, которому нужно "следовать", во втором - непосредственно раскрываются "обязательные" требования, свойства или обстоятельства.

Строго следовать "чему" (напр. "обычаю получать благословение" - существительное "обычаю" в дательном падеже).

Обязательно "что (чего и т.д.)" - напр. "благословение родителей на брак"; в других случаях существительное может быть в разных падежах), обязательно "что сделать" (получить благословение), обязательно "с каким" (напр. с зелёным), "где", "когда" и т. п. - т.е. "обязательно" может много с чем сочетаться.

Answer (score 0):

Строго следовать - соблюдать то, что предписано, в данном случае благословением. Например, "Благословить на вкушение постной пищи". Тогда "строго следовать благословению" - вкушать постную пишу.

"Обязательно благословение". "На послабление поста обязательно благословение". Т.е. без благословения послабление невозможно.

В общем-то смысл действительно сходный, но в персом случае речь идет предписании дейтвия, запрете иного. А во втором - о разрешении чего либо.